# How to create a hash object using lodash keyBy?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hi I have school data like this:

```
[
  {
    "details": {
      "campus": [
        {
          "address": "115-119...",
          "campusName": "blah",
          "email": "blah",
        }
      ],
      "colour": "#640E27",
      "schoolCode": "8383"
    },
    "enrolled": true,
    "id": "8383"

  }
]
```

I need to create a hash with school id as key and school colour as its value

```
    {'8383' : '#640E27'}
```

I m using lodash

```
  const hash = keyBy(action.payload, 'id');
  const reducedHash = pickBy(hash, item => item.details.colour);
```

However the output still has the whole object in value instead of just showing colour value.

How to achieve id and colour as key value of the hash?

Answer (score 2):

lodash keyBy may not be the best solution for your use case, instead you can use the [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```
action.payload.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator[currentValue.id] = currentValue.details.colour;
  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, Array.reduce is able to do the same job.

```
 let arr = [
    {
      details: {
        campus: [
          {
            address: '115-119...',
            campusName: 'blah',
            email: 'blah',
          },
        ],
        colour: '#640E27',
        schoolCode: '8383',
      },
      enrolled: true,
      id: '8383',
    },
  ];

  const reducedHash = arr.reduce((acc, data) => {
    return { ...acc, ...{ [data.id]: data.details.colour } };
  }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.forEach` or `.reduce`

```js
var data = [
  {
    "details": {
      "campus": [
        {
          "address": "115-119...",
          "campusName": "blah",
          "email": "blah",
        }
      ],
      "colour": "#640E27",
      "schoolCode": "8383"
    },
    "enrolled": true,
    "id": "8383"

  }
];
var res = {};
data.forEach(({id, details})=>{
 res[id] = details.colour
});

console.log(res);

//Reduce

var res2 = data.reduce((acc, {id, details})=>{
  return {...acc, ...{[id]:details.colour}}
}, {});

   console.log(res2)
```